# ¿Cómo sobreescribir una línea de un archivo txt en Java?

Tags: java, archivo

Por ejemplo, si tengo un archivo con el siguiente texto:

> Usuario_1,contrasena_1,Activo
>
> Usuario_2,contrasena_2,Activo
>
> Usuario_3,contrasena_3,Activo

y quiero cambiarlo para que quede asi:

> Usuario_1,contrasena_1,NO Activo
>
> Usuario_2,contrasena_2,Activo
>
> Usuario_3,contrasena_3,Activo

Solo quiero sobreescribir la linea 1 de ese archivo. He intentado con el `FileWriter`, sin embargo, con esa librería únicamente puedo escribir una linea al final, por lo que quedaría:

> Usuario_1,contrasena_1,Activo
>
> Usuario_2,contrasena_2,Activo
>
> Usuario_3,contrasena_3,Activo
>
> Usuario_1,contrasena_1,NO Activo

También he probado crear otro archivo en el que voy cambiando líneas del archivo actual y agregándolas al archivo nuevo, para finalmente eliminar el archivo previo. Funciona, sin embargo no pienso que sea lo más óptimo.

Comment: Puedes lograrlo con [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes enviarle como párametro la posición linea que quieres sobreescribir al método de ingresar, si también la linea modificada. prueba con esto:.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Archivo {
String ruta;
public Archivo() {

}

public Archivo(String ruta){
    this.ruta = ruta;
    try {
        File archivo = new File(this.ruta);
        this.ruta = archivo.getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public String leerArchivo(){
    String cadena = "";
    FileReader entrada = null;
    try {
        entrada = new FileReader(ruta);
        int c;
        while((c = entrada.read()) != -1){
            cadena += (char)c;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al leer archivo: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return cadena;
}

public void ingresar(String nuevaLinea, int posicion){
    FileWriter fichero = null;
    PrintWriter escritor = null;
    try {
        fichero = new FileWriter(ruta);
        escritor = new PrintWriter(fichero);
        escritor.flush();
        String split[] = leerArchivo().split("\n");
        split[posicion] = nuevaLinea;
        for(int x = 0; x < split.length; x++){
            escritor.write(split[x]);
            escritor.println();
         }
        escritor.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al escribir en el archivo de texto: "+e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if(fichero != null){
            try {
                fichero.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cerrar archivo de texto: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) podrías lograr esto, pero teniendo en cuenta que hay dos caracteres más a escribir `"NO"` por lo tanto para este ejemplo se necesita que la línea tenga 3 espacios más `Usuario_1,contrasena_1,Activo___`(_) espacios para luego hacer algo com esto

```
/* RW , para Lectura(Read) y Escritura (Writer) */
RandomAccessFile archivo = new RandomAccessFile("./Archivo.txt", "rw");
/* Posicionar al inicio del archivo, con seek te posicionas en el lugar 
 que desees del archivo */
archivo.seek(0);
/* Escribir la cadena */ 
archivo.writeBytes("Usuario_1,contrasena_1,NO Activo");
archivo.close();/* Cerrar el archivo importante */
```

La otra opción es leer todo el archivo y reemplazar la palabra de la línea para luego volver a escribir todo nuevamente (Prefiero RandomAccesFile)

```
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./Archivo.txt"));
    String line;String input = "";
    while((line = file.readLine()) != null){
        /* Podemos verificar si es Usuario_1 y \r\n es para hacer el 
          Salto de Línea y tener el formato original */
        if(line.contains("Usuario_1"))
            input += line.replaceAll("Activo", "NO Activo \r\n");
        else
            input += line+"\r\n";
    }
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("./Archivo.txt");
    fileOut.write(input.getBytes());
    fileOut.close();
```