# ¿Cómo puedo modificar una línea de un archivo .txt? (JAVA) Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

me gustaría saber cómo puedo modificar una línea de texto de un archivo .txt.

En el archivo la información está escrita de como "`nombre`,`puntos`".

Lo que necesito hacer es cambiar la información de `puntos`.

Sé cómo usar `BufferedReader` para leer el archivo y encontrar la línea con el `nombre` que necesito.

```
try {
  FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivo.getAbsoluteFile());
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
  String info;
  String infoAll = "";
  while ((info = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (info.contains(nombre)) {

    }
  }
} catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(Juego.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Pero no estoy muy seguro de cómo cambiar la información de esa línea en específico.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Acabé de revisar y veo tu pregunta duplicada: [¿Cómo sobreescribir una línea de un archivo txt en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29419/c%c3%b3mo-sobreescribir-una-l%c3%adnea-de-un-archivo-txt-en-java?rq=1)